# this.nextChild coming up undefined - mouseover/mouseout

Tags: javascript, undefined, parent-child, mouseover, mouseout

I'm a student and still learning, so my apologies if this is a silly question. Normally I can figure this out by sifting through other questions here, but I seem to be stuck this time.

I'm just trying to do a simple mouseover/mouseout, where when you mouse over the image, the image disappears and the text in the anchor tag changes to the name of the link (ie. hover over the house icon and it disappears and is replaced by "HOME"). I got that part working fine, but I can't get it to switch back to the icon when the mouse leaves the link. This is the current HTML for the link:

```
<li class="linksLi">
   <a id="#homeLink" data-namesrc="HOME" class="linksA">
      <img src="img/home.svg" alt="Home Icon" class="links">
   </a>
</li>
```

and then the javascript:

```
var linksImg = document.querySelectorAll(".links");
var linksName = document.querySelectorAll(".linksA");

function changeImg() {
    this.classList.add("hide");
    this.parentElement.innerHTML = this.parentElement.dataset.namesrc;  
}   

function changeName() {
    this.innerHTML = "";
    this.nextChild.classList.remove("hide");    
}


for (var i=0;i<linksImg.length;i++) {
    linksImg[i].addEventListener("mouseover", changeImg, false);
}

for (var j=0;j<linksName.length;j++) {
    linksName[j].addEventListener("mouseleave", changeName, false);
}
```

changeImg() is attached to the img tag, and changeName() is attached to the anchor tag. But my issue is in changeName(), when I try to remove the class "hide" from the child, it tells me the child is undefined (even though the img tag is clearly inside the a tag in the HTML). I've seen a lot of stuff regarding nodes and whitespace that I don't entirely understand, so I have no idea if that's what the issue is? Maybe this is a really basic problem and I'm missing something really obvious, I have no idea, but any help would be greatly appreciated!

**JAVASCRIPT ONLY PLEASE, no jQuery!**

Comment: There's nothing like `.nextChild` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try taking the event as a parameter to the functions and using "event.target" instead of "this"

```
function changeImg(evt) {
    evt.target.classList.add("hide");
    evt.target.parentElement.innerHTML = evt.target.parentElement.dataset.namesrc;  
}
```

"this" is a tricky keyword in JavaScript which can be many things depending on how the function is called.

And a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/v5zgnzmc/2/) for you.

**EDIT**
I have updated the JSFiddle to add/remove a span instead of setting innerHTML.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and the JSFiddle, but unfortunately its working the same as the code I originally posted.

Comment: You are setting this.innerHTML = "", and thus removing the child.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answers! For anyone wondering, I also got it working by making the img and anchor tags sibling, rather than the img being a child of the anchor tag. That way I could just target nextSibling in the js, and the issue of innerHTML creating an empty anchor tag and removing the img was no longer a problem.